# Gauging the "size" of measurable cardinals and inaccessible cardinals

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

I have been told that measurable cardinals are much "larger" than ordinary strongly inaccessible cardinals. I have even heard that the former make the latter look "tiny" in comparison. This is difficult for me to visualize.

Is there some way to gauge, intuitively, how much larger the smallest measurable cardinal is than the smallest strongly inaccessible cardinal?

Furthermore, can it be proven that the smallest strongly inaccessible cardinal is not measurable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one sense in which the least measurable is much larger than the least inaccessible: Let $\kappa$ be the smallest measurable cardinal. Then the set of inaccessible cardinals $<\kappa$ has size $\kappa$. Jech's book has details on this (and much stronger) results.

---

Let me sketch why the least measurable has to be so big. Let $\kappa$ be measurable, with a $\kappa$-complete measure $\mathcal{U}$. We can consider the ultrapower of the entire universe by this measure, $\prod V/\mathcal{U}$. This might seem iffy, but by Scott's trick this structure can naturally be identified with a definable class, so that the "$\in$"-relation is again definable; so we may talk about this ultrapower in the universe of sets.

The structure $\prod V/\mathcal{U}$ is well-founded, since $\mathcal{U}$ is $\kappa$- (specifically, countably-)complete, so we may take its Mostowski collapse; that is, we have some transitive proper class $M$ such that $(M, \in)$ is isomorphic to $\prod V/\mathcal{U}$ via a map $m$. (Again, I'm sweeping a bunch of technical details under the table, but this all works.) The usual embedding of a structure into its own ultrapower now yields a map $j: V\rightarrow M$; this map is an elementary embedding.

Moreover, this map is nontrivial: $j(\kappa)$ is an ordinal strictly larger than $\kappa$! And $\kappa$ is the least such cardinal moved (the *critical point* of $j$). To see that $\kappa$ is moved, note that by transfinite induction, for each $\alpha<\kappa$ we have $j(\alpha)=\alpha$; meanwhile, consider the element of the ultrapower $x=m([(\alpha)_{\alpha<\kappa}]_{\mathcal{U}})$, the (Mostowski collapse of) the equivalence class of the identity sequence. By elementarity, $x$ is an ordinal $<j(\kappa)$; but also $x>j(\alpha)$ for every $\alpha<x$, since $\mathcal{U}$ is $\kappa$-complete. So $j(\kappa)>\kappa$.

So what? Well, lots of "small" large cardinal properties - inaccessible, weakly compact, etc. - are $\Pi_1$. If $\mu$ has some $\Pi_1$ property in $V$, then $\mu$ also has that property in any inner model; $\Pi_1$ properties are *downwards absolute*. So let $\kappa$ be the least measurable. If $\kappa$ were also the least inaccessible, then there would be a contradiction: by elementarity, $M\models$"$j(\kappa$) is the least inaccessible," but by absoluteness $M\models$"$\kappa$ is inaccessible."

Similarly, the least measurable can't be the second weakly compact, . . . , the (least inaccessible)th weakly compact,  . . . measurables are freakin' HUGE! (Except not nearly as huge as, well, *huge* cardinals. :P)

See Jech's book for more details.

Comment: I guess $\omega$ is not considered a measurable cardinal?

Comment: Interesting. Is the converse also true? That is, do we need to assume the existence of measurable cardinals to show that there exists an inaccessible cardinal $\kappa$ that contains $\kappa$ smaller inaccessible cardinals?

Comment: @bof No, $\omega$ is not considered a measurable cardinal (or inaccessible, or weakly compact, or . . . ) since uncountability is assumed in the definition. (If you prefer to let $\omega$ be a large cardinal, just stick the word "uncountable" everywhere in my answer.)

Comment: @MikeBattaglia No - what you've just described is vastly weaker. A *Mahlo* cardinal is an inacessible $\kappa$ with stationary (and hence $\kappa$-many) inaccessibles below it. Any measurable cardinal will, again, have itself-many smaller Mahlos. Measurable cardinals are really, *really* big.

Comment: @MikeBattaglia Actually, what you've described is a 1-inaccessible (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inaccessible_cardinal#.CE.B1-inaccessible_cardinals_and_hyper-inaccessible_cardinals); but Mahlos are more common, so that's why I mentioned them.

Comment: Hi @NoahSchweber, it's many years later but I am revisiting this question and it makes better sense to me now. One thing I don't quite get is how to show that this ultrapower will be well-founded, though. For instance, as you note, there will be elements like $(0, 1, 2, 3 ..., \omega, \omega+1, ...)$ and so on, up to $\kappa$, which are nonstandard ordinals greater than anything less than $\kappa$ but less than $\kappa$. But why is it not possible to create an infinite descending chain of nonstandard ordinals?

Comment: My first thought is to look at, for instance, the element $(0,0,1,1,2,2,..., \omega, \omega, \omega+1, \omega+1, ...)$ and so on, again up to $\kappa$. This grows more slowly than the previous nonstandard element "almost everywhere", and thus is also greater than every ordinal less than $\kappa$, unless the set of indices equal to 0 mod $\omega$ is in the ultrafilter. Wouldn't one be able to get an infinite descending chain of nonstandard ordinals by playing around with this kind of thing?

Comment: @MikeBattaglia This is what **countable completeness** does for us! Suppose $\alpha_i\in\mathsf{Ord}^\kappa$ $(i\in\omega)$ were (representatives of) elements of the ultrapower such that in the ultrapower we have $\alpha_0>\alpha_1>\alpha_2>...$. By Los' Theorem, for each $i\in\omega$ we have $$D_i:=\{\eta: \alpha_i(\eta)>\alpha_{i+1}(\eta)\}\in\mathcal{U}.$$ Since $\mathcal{U}$ is countably complete, the intersection $X:=\bigcap_{i\in\omega}D_i$ is in $\mathcal{U}$ ... hence nonempty. Pick $n\in X$; then we have $$\alpha_0(n)>\alpha_1(n)>\alpha_2(n)>...,$$ a contradiction.

Comment: More broadly, we have the following: an ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$ is countably complete iff it satisfies the strengthening of Los' theorem to $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega_1}$. And that logic can express well-foundedness. There's a general idea here that stronger closure properties on ultrafilters imply stronger Los-style properties; interestingly, some basic-seeming questions here appear open *(at risk of self-promotion see e.g. my MO questions [1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/407374/), [2](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/409423/can-there-be-no-surprisingly-averageable-second-ord))*!

Comment: This stronger Losian phenomenon, incidentally, is the "real" reason measurable cardinals are so large.

Comment: Thanks @NoahSchweber, that makes sense! So I get that the real idea is this countably complete ultrafilter, and the existence of that is the same as the existence of a measurable cardinal. What does the notation $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega_1}$ mean?

Comment: I also don't get how when you embed each set into the ultrapower via the constant embedding $S \to (S, S, S, ...)$ and so on, $\kappa$-many times, this doesn't run into Kunen's theorem. After all, the ultrapower is just a bunch of $\kappa$ sequences, and the class of all $\kappa$ sequences is a subclass of the class all possible sets, so it would seem like we have a nontrivial elementary embedding of $V$ into itself, but Kunen's theorem says this isn't possible. Posted that here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4450750/measurable-cardinals-elementary-embeddings-and-kunens-theorem