# Measurable cardinals, elementary embeddings, and Kunen's theorem

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory, filters, large-cardinals

Suppose $\kappa$ is a measurable cardinal. Then if $U$ is the ultrafilter on $\kappa$, we can use this to generate an ultrapower of the entire universe. We can then embed $V$ into this ultrapower in the usual way, such that every set $S$ maps into the constant $\kappa$-sequence in which every entry is equal to $S$. (Noah Schweber has a good answer explaining this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1432758/gauging-the-size-of-measurable-cardinals-and-inaccessible-cardinals/1432785)).

What I don't get is: we can form the Mostowski collapse, giving us a transitive class $M$ which is isomorphic to the ultrapower. Then the embedding of $V$ into the ultrapower gives an nontrivial elementary embedding $j: V \to M$, of which the measurable cardinal $\kappa$ is the critical point.

*But*, shouldn't the ultrapower of $V$, and thus $M$, both be subclasses of all of $V$? So wouldn't this lead to an embedding of $V$ into itself? But Kunen's theorem says we can't have a nontrivial elementary embedding of $V$ into itself.

My reasoning: to form the ultrapower we first take the Cartesian power $V^\kappa$, which is the class of all $\kappa$-length tuples of sets -- and since each of these tuples can be formalized as a set in the usual way, we clearly have a subclass of the entire universe $V$ of all possible sets. Then, when we map $V$ into these sequences, we're embedding $V$ into a proper subclass of itself. Then we quotient by the ultrafilter, and we can use Scott's trick to get a set-representative for each equivalence class, and again the result should be a proper subclass of $V$. Thus the embedding of $V$ into the ultrapower is again a map from $V$ into this proper subclass of itself.

We then use the Mostowski collapse to get a transitive class $M$ which is isomorphic to the ultrapower. This $M$ must somehow *not* be a subclass of $V$, I think, or else we would be embedding $V$ into itself, which is impossible via Kunen's theorem. But if there's a bijection with $M$ and the ultrapower, and if the ultrapower is a proper subclass of $V$, then we'd have an embedding of $M$ back into $V$, and thus a nontrivial elementary embedding of $V$ into itself.

Why isn't this a dealbreaker for measurable cardinals?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ultrapower $(\mathrm{Ult}_U, E_U)$ is not a subclass of $(V, \in)$ since it uses a completely different membership relation. Its transitive collapse $(M,\in),$ on the other hand, is a subclass of $(V,\in).$

The map underlying the ultrapower embedding $(V,\in)\to (\mathrm{Ult}_U, E_U)$ is certainly a map $V\to V,$ but that's not the same thing as having an embedding $(V,\in)\to (V,\in).$ Similarly, the isomorphism $(M,\in)\to (\mathrm{Ult}_U, E_U)$ does not add up to an embedding $(M,\in)\to (V,\in).$

And the fact that $(M,\in)$ is a subclass of $(V,\in)$ doesn't run afoul of Kunen. While we do have an elementary embedding $j:(V,\in)\to (M,\in),$ $j$ is not elementary when viewed as an embedding $(V,\in)\to (V,\in).$

Comment: OK, thanks, that makes sense. So when we embed $V$ into $M$, the resulting structure has certain properties such that the embedding is elementary. Then, when we add the rest of $V$ back in, some of those properties (I guess particularly involving "for all" quantifiers) may not hold because there are now more sets to quantify over, and so it wouldn't be elementary. Is that the idea?

Comment: Also, do we know what the class $M$ looks like? In particular, is every set within $V$ of cardinality less than the first measurable cardinal also in $M$?

Comment: @MikeBattaglia Yes, that's the idea. An example would be "$\kappa$ is a cardinal." One can show that $j(\kappa)>\kappa$ and $j(\kappa)$ is not a cardinal, so that fails elementarity if we view $j$ as a map $V\to V.$ But since $j:V\to M$ *is* elementary, $j(\kappa)$ is a measurable cardinal in $M$. Every set with *hereditary* cardinality $<\kappa$ is in $M$ since $j$ is the identity on $V_\kappa$, and for slightly less straightforward reasons, $M$ also includes all sets of rank $\kappa$. But some sets of rank $\kappa+1$ are missing from $M$... most notably $U.$

Comment: @MikeBattaglia (Another way to look at the main issue is that, while $M$ is an  submodel of $V$ that is elementarily equivalent to $V,$ it is not an elementary submodel of $V$. Same phenomenon in a simpler situation would looking at $([0,1], \le)$ as a submodel of $([0,2],\le).$)

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense - but how can one show that $j(\kappa)$ is not a cardinal? I would have expected it to be.

Comment: @MikeBattaglia Every ordinal less than $j(\kappa)$ is represented in the ultrapower as a function $\kappa\to \kappa,$ so $|j(\kappa)| \le 2^\kappa.$ On the other hand, $j(\kappa)$ is a strong limit cardinal in $M,$ so $j(\kappa)>(2^\kappa)^M$, and as I mentioned before, $V_{\kappa+1}\subseteq M$, so $P(\kappa)\cap M= P(\kappa)$ and thus $(2^{\kappa})^M\ge 2^{\kappa}$. So we have $2^\kappa < j(\kappa) < (2^\kappa)^+.$ (Another example of elementarity failing that's more immediate is if $\kappa$ is the *least* measurable... $j(\kappa)>\kappa,$ so $j(\kappa)$ certainly can't have *that* property)

Comment: Hi @spaceisdarkgreen, just getting to see this now... What is the difference between $P(\kappa)$ and $2^\kappa$ above? I can see how it must be less than $2^\kappa$ and greater than $(2^\kappa)^M$. I guess I just don't get - so the model is adding *extra* sets to it's interpretation of the power set of $\kappa$ then?

Comment: @MikeBattaglia $P(\kappa)$ is the set of all subsets of $\kappa$ and $2^{\kappa}$ is the cardinality of $P(\kappa),$ i.e. the least ordinal that has a bijection with it. $M$ is a submodel so it can't add more sets (but $P(\kappa)\subseteq M$ in this case so it doesn't lose any either)... what could potentially happen though is that $M$ could be missing some bijections between $P(\kappa)$ and ordinals, so the least ordinal in bijection with $P(\kappa)$ could be greater in $M.$